# how to update and redraw android.app.dialog?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I'm writing an android app.

I have an open dialog (android.app.dialog).

I want to update one of the textViews in that dialog.

How can i do this without closing and reopening the dialog?

today the assignment requires opening the dialog.

```
    setDlgData();

    mDialog.show();
```

Comment: Instead of setData you can do addContentView() like in AlertDilaog and show the revised content on some action...

Comment: what do you mean `on some action`? I don't want the user to do anything to see the update. I want it to just update when needed

Comment: ok then in that case i would suggest you follow @Waqas advice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Dialog`, use `AlertDialog` and call `setMessage` on it to change the text inside.

Comment: it's a legacy code. Will it affect the UI somehow if I do so?

Comment: @EladBenda it depends what else are you showing in your custom dialog. If its just a message and **ok/cancel** buttons, then I would suggest you to make use of `AlertDialog`. Its purpose is to serve dialogs with ease and simplicity.

Comment: I have tried to switch to `alertDialog` and go an exception: `mDialog = new AlertDialog(mContext, R.style.Dialog);` error: `The constructor AlertDialog(Context, int) is not visible`

Comment: then get the reference of that `TextView` which shows your message string and alter it at your will

Comment: try like this `mDialog = new AlertDialog(mContext);`

Comment: then `Dialog show()` should work as well, no? just like `AlertDialog show()`

Comment: show() would work just fine since AlertDialog is extended from Dialog